# Terminate PowerShell process after script executing

Tags: powershell, msbuild, cmd

I have a TFS Build where I run PowerShell script. The problem is PowerShell.exe never stops after runnig and do nothing.
Script is signed by trusted sertificate and successfully runs on my BuildAgent from PowerShell and writes logs. But it don't to anything from build or from cmd.exe. PowerShell.exe just starts and do nothing.

P.S. PS script have Exit commands but it not help.

Thanks,
Roman

Comment: It could be helpful to show how you are running your PowerShell script from TFS.

Comment: <Exec Command="Powershell.exe &quot;&amp; '$(DropLocation)\$(BuildNumber)\Release\Scripts\Post-Deployment\PostBuildTasks_Lviv.ps1' '$(DropLocation)' '$(BuildNumber)' '$(BuildDefinitionName)' 'SmartDrive' 'Release' 'Dev_GLTeam1' 'smartdrive-srv2' '$(GetVersion)'&quot;" WorkingDirectory="$(DropLocation)\$(BuildNumber)\Release"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved.
Problem was security settings on BuildAgent. When I run script manually from BuildAgent user's account and choose "Run always" build starts working correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use, `Stop-Process -Id $PID` from within the script to end the current PowerShell process.

Comment: Still not working from build.
I run PS script from build by
<Exec Command="Powershell.exe &quot;&amp; '$(DropLocation)\$(BuildNumber)\Release\Scripts\Post-Deployment\PostBuildTasks_Lviv.ps1' '$(DropLocation)' '$(BuildNumber)' '$(BuildDefinitionName)' 'SmartDrive' 'Release' 'Dev_GLTeam1' 'smartdrive-srv2' '$(GetVersion)'&quot;" WorkingDirectory="$(DropLocation)\$(BuildNumber)\Release"/>

Comment: Is there more than one PowerShell process running during the build?

Comment: Well done @Rynant, this worked for me. I have no idea why exit at the bottom of the script was not ending the process, and returning to cmd.exe